# Method not supported using Auth::login()

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to login from a parent account to a son account
I tried this 
Route:

```
 Route::middleware('can:isTutor')->group(function() {

       Route::POST('/redirect','TuteurEtudiantController@loginkid')->name('loginkid');

    });
```

Function:

```
public function loginkid(Request $request){
    $id= $request->input('id');
    $user = User::find($id);
    Auth::login($user);

}
```

The data come in the $etudiants variable in my view

```
 @foreach($etudiants as $etudiant)
       <tr>
           <td>{{$etudiant->name }}</td>
           <td>{{$etudiant->id }}</td>
           <td>
           <form action="{{route('loginkid')}}" method="GET" >
                           {{csrf_field()}}
                      <input hidden name="id" value="{{ $etudiant->id }}">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbspSe connecter</button>
           </form>

           </td>

       </tr>
       @endforeach
```

When I try to log using the button "Se connecter" 
I get the error

```
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

My controller, in case something can help by knowing what are the functions that I have on it

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\TuteurEtudiant;

class TuteurEtudiantController extends Controller


{

    public function createlink(){
        $etudiants = User::where('type','=','etudiant')->get();
        $tuteurs = User::where('type','=','tuteur')->get();


        return view('manageMe.createlink',['tuteurs'=>$tuteurs,'etudiants'=>$etudiants]);
    }
    public function storelink(Request $request){

        $lien = new TuteurEtudiant();
        $lien->tuteur_id=$request->input('tuteur');
        $lien->etudiant_id=$request->input('etudiant');
        $lien->save();
        return redirect()->back()->withMessage('Lien de parenté créé avec succées!');

    }


    public function loginkid(Request $request){
        $id= $request->input('id');
        $user = User::find($id);
        Auth::login($user);

    }

}
```

Comment: I would start by verifying the route is what you expect. What do you see in the output of php artisan route:list ? Is it possible this definition of the route is not being loaded or is being overwritten?

Comment: This error is because `loginkid` is a post route and you are submitting form as get route.

Comment: @akhtarMunir should I change to poost in the form? method="POST" ? already tried this and it's not working

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper I did the command and I noticed that /redirect is 
|        | POST     | redirect                                                     | loginkid                 | App\Http\Controllers\TuteurEtudiantController@loginkid                 | web,can:isTutor

Comment: @MEHDIELAISSI ofcourse it will work, you might be missing something, but use post route in form.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir  No it didn't work I used post method in form and I kept Post method in the route but nothing same error ""The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."
"

Comment: is this `TuteurEtudiantController` controller a resource controller ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I shared my controller on the post please check because I don't get what do you means

Comment: when `dd($request->input('id'));` does it shows an id ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I don't reach it at all it's like I don't even reach the loginkid function yet and I get this error "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."
again

Comment: change this `<input hidden name="id" value="{{ $etudiant->id }}">` to this `<input type='hidden' name="id" value="{{ $etudiant->id }}">`

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I did and nothing changed same error

Comment: Okay try one thing, leave `GET` method in your form tag and remove `{{ csrf_field() }}` and in route change `Route::post` to `Route::any`

Comment: @AkhtarMunir It's not working :(

Comment: Fixed it I had to post to the same route from where I start that means /home instead of /redirect Thank you so much @AkhtarMunir for your help bro

Answer (score 0):

Actually the parent log to `/home` and do this in the view where with the route `/home` 
So when you have to post the data you have to post it to the same route `/home`

```
Route::middleware('can:isTutor')->group(function() {

   Route::post('/home','TuteurEtudiantController@loginkid')->name('loginkid');

});
```